# Problem Using QuerySelectMultipleField in Flask-Admin Edit Form

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm newly come to Flask-Admin, and I'm trying to customize a model edit form. My User model has a `roles` attribute which is a `relationship` through the `role_users` table to `Role.name`, with a foreign key constraint.

Everything works so far, except that the Flask-Admin default User edit form renders `roles` as a string field. I'd like to render it as a QuerySelectMultipleField. My models are:

```
from flask import current_app
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from app import db, login_manager

roles = db.Table(
    'role_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('users.username')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.String(80), db.ForeignKey('roles.name')),
    db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'role_id')
)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    
    def __init__(self, username='', password=''):
        default = Role.query.filter_by(name='View_contact').one()
        self.roles.append(default)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
    
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
    
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
    
    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('Password is not a readable attribute.')
    
    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.set_password(password)
    
    # Required for user_loader with non-integer User PK not named 'id'
    def get_id(self):
        return self.username
    
    def grant_role(self, role_name):
        if not self.has_role(role_name):
            role = Role.query.filter_by(name=role_name).first()
            self.roles.append(role)
            db.session.commit()
    
    def revoke_role(self, role_name):
        if self.has_role(role_name):
            role = Role.query.filter_by(name=role_name).first()
            self.roles.remove(role)
    
    def has_role(self, role_name):
        for role in self.roles:
            if role.name == role_name:
                return True
        
        return False


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    return User.query.get(str(username))
    

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    role_list = [
        'View_contact',
        'Add_contact',
        'Edit_contact',
        'Delete_contact',
        'View_user',
        'Add_user',
        'Edit_user',
        'Delete_user',
        'Admin',
    ]
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role {}>'.format(self.name)
    
    @classmethod
    def load_roles(cls):
        for role_name in cls.role_list:
            role = Role.query.filter_by(name=role_name).first()
            if role is None:
                role = Role(name=role_name)
                db.session.add(role)
        
        db.session.commit()
```

My custom ModelView is

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.fields import QuerySelectMultipleField, QuerySelectField
from flask_admin.form import Select2TagsWidget, Select2Widget
from wtforms import PasswordField

from app import db
from app.models import Role, User

class UserView(ModelView):
    column_display_pk = True
    form_extra_fields = {
        'password': PasswordField('Password'),
        'role_sel': QuerySelectMultipleField(
            label='Roles',
            query_factory=lambda: Role.query.all,
            widget=Select2TagsWidget()
        )
    }
    
    form_columns = (
        'username',
        'password',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'role_sel',
    )
    
    def on_model_change(self, form, User, is_created):
        if form.password.data != '':
            User.set_password(form.password.data)
```

but when I try to access `admin/user/new/` or `admin/user/edit` Flask throws `AttributeError: 'QuerySelectMultipleField' object has no attribute '_value'`.

If I try changing from `QuerySelectMultipleField & Select2TagsWidget` to `QuerySelectField & Select2Widget` Flask throws `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is `_value()` a method I need to implement? I'm using Flask-Admin 1.5.8.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i think you should use another naming system for your tables:

```py
# change this to roles_users
roles = db.Table(
    'role_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('users.username')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.String(80), db.ForeignKey('roles.name')),
    db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'role_id')
)
```

Now, moving to a possible solution:

Even though you think you dont need an `id` attribute (or column) on your `User` and `Role`models, it is kinda default to use `id` as the primary key for models. Many extensions and frameworks will work "as is" if you just follow the patterns.

I think that what is going wrong with your implementation, is that FlaskAdmin's ModelView is having troubles when defining the `Roles` model primary key.

Try the following code:

```py
class Role(db.Model):
    ...
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    ...


roles = db.Table(
    'role_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('users.username')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.String(80), db.ForeignKey('roles.id')),
    db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'role_id')
)
```

and remove the `role_sel` from your `form_args`, and `form_columns` in the `UserView`.

FlaskAdmin should guess that the `User.roles` is a many-to-many field and render it as a multi select field.

Answer (score 0):

your error is where your secondary needs to be pointed to the

role_users table where the relationship is kept track

```
lass User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=role_users)
```